# Как исключить одинаковые результаты запроса?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Запрос выводит несколько одинаковых результатов, но как сделать так, чтобы он выводил один единственный?

```
SELECT Clients.Surname, Clients.Name, Existing_connections.Tariff_name, Tariffs.Salary
FROM (Tariffs INNER JOIN ((Existing_connections INNER JOIN Housing ON Existing_connections.ID_housing = Housing.ID_housing) INNER JOIN Clients ON Housing.ID_client = Clients.ID_client)
ON Existing_connections.Tariff_name = Tariffs.Tariff_name)
```

Вот результат запроса:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте

```
SELECT DISTINCT column1, column2, ...
FROM table_name;
```

Попробовать можете тут  https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

Comment: спасибо, сработало)

Comment: @vanyavanya пожалуйста, отметьте ответ, что он помог вам, нажав на галочку

Comment: @Insider DISTINCT будет работать корректно только при условии, что выводится одно значение, можно попробовать GROUP BY

Comment: + предлагаю дополнить ответ вариантом через GROUP BY и через TOP в случае когда нужна только одна запись по конкретному клиенту